# Can I use JavaScript in 'Edit in DataSheet' mode?

Tags: javascript, datasheet

I would like to use some JavaScript in 'Edit in DataSheet' mode to check a value and prompt a user to enter some text.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry but you can't. The DataSheet mode uses a "SEALED" ActiveX Control. You have no control over the markup of this control(use IE Dev Toolbar and check it out) in order to control client side behaviour.

Comment: hm.. thanks will check it out with IE DevTool Toolbar

Comment: Hi There. To meet the needs of your requirement, I suggest using some sort of a Databound AJAX or ASP.NET Control. Obviously you need to bind the control to your Sharepoint list using .Net or the Sharepoint Client OM.

Answer (score 0):

In SP2013 you can run javascript on top of datasheet view.

```
function CodeToRun(){//code here}

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CodeToRun, "callout.js");
```